# Strange issues with selenium after upgrading to chromedriver 2.28 & chrome v57

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

We are seeing a strange issue with our automation scripts after upgrading chromedriver & chrome version-

1. When we run some tests through our automation scripts they run very slow than earlier (almost taking double the time they were taking previously)
2. While running the scripts at times web page become unresponsive for few seconds e.g. while entering some text in a text box one character typed at a time and then become unresponsive for few seconds around 2-5 seconds and then the next character will be typed

Has anyone seen this behavior ?

I understand that there was a issue fixed in ChromeDriver v2.28 (Fixes a bug which caused ChromeDriver to timeout and/or hang randomly while a dialog is showing.) I am not sure but suspecting that it can be related to this

Comment: Interesting, can you provide us some information about your Development & Selenium Test environment? 1. What is your web development environment? DotNet, Java, PHP, Angularjs? 2. How is your framework? Datadriven or Hybrid? 3. Are you using PageFactory? 4. Are you using any other framework? TestNG ? 5. When you say "unresponsive" is that what you see visually or your testcase fails?